# BASH Script: Why Do My Variables Not Work

Tags: bash, script, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to use some script variables in a BASH script to make my code clearer.

However, for some reason, my variables are not being expanded/used.

Nothing happens when I use the variable with the full command spelled out

This is the script I made :

```
command1=$SOMEPATH/abc.sh
command2=$SOMEPATH/def.sh input
command3=$SOMEPATH/ghi

 gnome-terminal                                                                   \
 --tab -t "Server 1"  -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"$command1\"; exec bash"'  \
 --tab -t "Server 2"  -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"$command2";  exec bash"' \
 --tab -t "Server 3"  -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"$command3";  exec bash"'
```

Thanks for any tips

Comment: Single quotes prevent expansion of variables. Use double quotes to save blanks: `command2="$SOMEPATH/def.sh input"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variables in double quotes

```
command1="$SOMEPATH/abc.sh"
command2="$SOMEPATH/def.sh input"
command3="$SOMEPATH/ghi"
```

Hope this helps!